# How to Modify/Update a .CSV file through VB 6.0

Tags: csv, vb6

I have a .CSV File with 5 values in a row , i want to modify the file in a way i should add one more value in the Beginning/End/Middle of the row.

How to add a new row with a set of values in the .CSV File?

How to do this in a simple way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no magic way to insert things into the middle of a stream file (such as any text file including CSV files).

So this means you need to read the old file and modify it as you go writing a new file out.

There are many ways to do this though:

- Read the input file into memory as a blob and work on it there then write out the modified data.
- Read/write it with changes line by line.
- Use Jet Text IISAM, Log Parser's COM API, etc. which allow SQL and SQL-like operations on text data in tabular formats such as CSV.

The simplest and most general way is line by line read/modify/write.  This can be slower than the "blob" approach for small to middling files but doesn't risk the headaches that may result when a large file must be processed.

For very large files this can be optimized by reading, parsing, modifying, then writing in "chunks" to minimize I/O costs.  But this can also be more complex to program correctly.

Comment: Bob77, will you please help me with some piece of code, from there i will improvise

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code may help , this is not an answer but it will help

```
Dim line As String
Dim arrayOfElements() As String
Dim linenumber As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim opLine As String
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim ts As TextStream

line = ""

Open strPath For Input As #1 ' Open file for input
    Do While Not EOF(1) ' Loop until end of file
        linenumber = linenumber + 1
        Line Input #1, line
        arrayOfElements = Split(line, "|")
       If Not linenumber = 1 Then
            If UBound(arrayOfElements) = 2 Then
               line = line & "|x|y"
               opLine = opLine & line & vbCrLf
            End If
        Else
        line = line & "|col4|col5"
         opLine = opLine & line & vbCrLf
       End If
```

Loop

```
Close #1 ' Close file.
Set ts = fso.CreateTextFile(strPath, True)
ts.WriteLine (opLine)
ts.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

fso need to be closed!

`Set fso = Nothing`